# Angular 6: how to pass a username and password to an API?

Tags: angular

Help, please. I'm just not getting this -- I have an API that I am requesting a list of homes from but I'm not able to pass the username and password to (getting an unauthorized access return). My various attempts at passing this info are falling flat.

My specific question is: how and where do I pass the user name and password (in getHomes()?)?

Thank you.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  auth = ('user:password');
  endpoint = 'https://api.com';
  httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa(this.auth),
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res;
  return body || { };
}

getHomes(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.endpoint + 'houses').pipe(
    map(this.extractData));
}
```

Comment: you can pass httpoptionns as a parameter to `http.get method this.http.get(this.endpoint + '/houses',httpOptions)` see https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

First of all your RestService code has some strange issues, assigning httpOptions hangs in the middle. Probably you need to place within the constructor or within getHomes method.
Then you can pass the httpOptions  as follows

```
http.get method this.http.get(this.endpoint + '/houses',httpOptions) //assign it here
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm trying to understand what you mean by httpOptions hanging in the middle. I'm working on it and will let you know if I get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the headers as `any` in the class:

```js
    headers:any;
```

Assign the values of the headers in the constructor:

```js
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders({      
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Encoding': 'none',
          'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa(this.auth)
        });
    }
```

And pass the headers into the get method this way:

```js
    this.http.get(this.endpoint + '/houses', {headers:this.headers});
```